# fluentd --dry-run FAILS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-20.04, fluentd

Here is the list of the installed package versions.

```
$ruby -v
ruby 3.1.1p18 (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) [x86_64-linux]
$gem -v
3.3.7
$fluentd --version
fluentd 1.14.6
```

`$fluentd --dry-run`

After running the above command getting the following error.

```
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/config.rb:31:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/fluent/fluent.conf (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/config.rb:31:in `open'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/config.rb:31:in `build'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:747:in `configure'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:355:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.14.6/bin/fluentd:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/bin/fluentd:25:in `load'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/bin/fluentd:25:in `<main>'
```

```
$echo '{"json":"message"}' | fluent-cat debug.test
connect failed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
connect failed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
connect failed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
connect failed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
connect failed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
connect failed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 24224
exceed retry limit
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a config file on `/etc/fluent/fluent.conf` or start the server with `-c /path/to/config`